# How to update the state in URL without Navigating it in GWT MVP

Tags: navigation, reload, page-refresh, gwt-mvp

I am a GWT beginner.

I wanted to bookmark the GWT application developed using MVP.

I have a state where user can narrow down the search results by selecting search criteria on the page. If the user selects any criteria, search results will be fetched thru AJAX and displayed on the page.

Now I want to bookmark it.

The problem here is the URL doesnot contain which search criterai selected.

I want something to update the URL with out refresh/reload the page.

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Activities and Places design pattern:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces

It allows bookmarking any place within the app with whatever parameters you need for that particular place. For example, your URL may look like:

myApp.com/#SEARCH:user=123&key=xyz

Your search Activity will read this token and process it as you need it without reloading the page. You will also be able to "create" these URLs without reloading the page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually, I want to refresh the page or share the link with the friend so that the search criteria I selected should get applied.

Comment: This is exactly what you can do with this design pattern.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more specific? I use the MVP design pattern only.

Comment: Read the article. Activities and Places pattern can be used with the MVP pattern.